# How to change resetting password of django

Tags: python, django

I am learning to use django and my question is if it is possible to change the system to reset the users' password, the default system of sending a link by mail I do not want to use it, my idea is to send a code to reset the password , but I don't know how it should be done and if possible, I would also need to know if it's safe.

What I want is for the user who wants to recover his password to go to the recovery section, fill in his email and choose to send and enable a field to put the code that was sent to the mail.

I don't know how I should do it or is there a package for this?

Thank you very much people greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, when user clicks on reset password ask for users email id, verify that email id provided is same as what you have in DB. If the email id matches you can generate a OTP and save it in DB(for specific time duration like 3 mins) and send it to user's Email id. Now User enters the OTP. If the OTP provided by user matches the one you have in DB, open the page where user can enter new password.

Comment: I apologize for the bad tradition of google. What I am trying to do is that in the process of resetting the user's password a random code is sent to their email, and that code is used in a template, if it is correct, the user can enter their new password. I don't want to use links via email but a code.

Comment: Updated the answer, You can simply generate a code in backend and save it in DB and send it to user via email. User can enter this code and verify it against the one saved it DB, if it matches, User should be allowed to reset the password.

Comment: I was researching but I couldn't find a code clue to guide me and do it. I do not know where to start. I've searched all over Google and didn't find answers :/